# Unknown Build Error using WPF Toolkit

Tags: wpftoolkit, autocompletebox

I installed the Feb 2010 WPF Toolkit as I'm interested in evaluating the AutoCompleteBox control and I'm having extremely limited success. I can get the control to work, but as soon as I try and set any of it's properties in XAML, I get the following:

*Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'WPFToolkit, Version=3.5.40128.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.*

I've been testing this on a blank WPF window in a new solution. I'm guessing I'm just missing a reference or something... Here's the XAML (I've added nothing to the .xaml.cs):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfToolkitApplication.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Height="25"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The only reference I've added is System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add a reference to WPFToolkit.dll (Not just System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit).

Answer (score 2):

I've hit this, and was able to work around it.  I had multiple projects in my solution: A is a C# library that uses VSM and references WPFToolkit.dll.  B is a WPF Application that includes A in its XAML, and B has a project reference to A.

When I got the error, I was able to resolve it by adding a reference to WPFToolkit.dll in B.  I'm going to try to distill this issue to a simple repro and file it as a bug for the Visual Studio team.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VisualStudio 2010 you need to unblock this assembly making it a trusted assembly. See this article for details.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890038(VS.100).aspx

After adding the reference (following the instructions above) you still need to add this line to your windows xaml.