# Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'WPFToolkit, Version=3.5.40128.1, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'am trying to code an accordion menu in WPF (viusual studio 2010,Target Framework:.Net Framework 4 client Profile)
I have this error,since I added the references :

System.Windows.wontrols.Layout.Toolkit.dll 
WPFToolkit.extended.dll

[image]

this is what I mentionned in the xaml reference:

```
<Window x:Class="GMAO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:System_Windows_Controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit"
        Title="GMAO" Height="572" Width="672" Icon="/GMAO;component/images/Mastercom1.png" Background="#9DB9EB" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
```

thanks for help

Comment: Help pleaze I followed this question but I always get the same problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447657/unknown-build-error-using-wpf-toolkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to download and add the reference WPFToolkit.dll http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535

That is what the error points to.

**EDIT:**

It is probably already installed - just make sure that you add it as reference alongside the extended - [Unknown Build Error using WPF Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447657/unknown-build-error-using-wpf-toolkit)

Comment: Hi Eugene Podskal and thanks for your reply,I just done that,I have installed the WPFtoolkit and added the reference to "WPFToolkit.design.dll" file but always the same problem

Comment: I didn't find the WPFToolkit.dll file in the downloaded folder

Comment: It is called WPFToolkit.dll. *.Design is not the missing library.